# Cron running but CMD not working

Tags: server, cron

I just switched to an Ubuntu 14.04 server from an 11.04 server. In /var/spool/cron/crontabs/root I have the line:

```
* * * * * /root/arewerunning.sh > /root/appmon.log
```

arewerunning.sh looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

if P=$(pgrep aserver)
then
  echo  " "
else
  echo "aserver has stopped. System Will reboot"
sudo reboot now
fi
```

On the 11.04 server this was working. Whenever I killed aserver the system would reboot. But on 14.04 the command appears to be running but the system does not restart. 
cron.log looks like:

```
(root) CMD (/root/arewerunning.sh > /root/appmon.log)
```

when the process hasn't been killed and like:

```
(root) CMD (/root/arewerunning.sh > /root/appmon.log)
(CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
```

when the process has been killed. I know that the MTA line is because it is trying to email me and it can't, but that shouldn't prevent the reboot.

I have tried running the command outside of cron and it works just fine. I'm using a direct path so that shouldn't be a problem. I have also tried adding "sh" in front of the command. appmon.log isn't showing anything. I've tried putting other commands in the file and they work just fine.

Comment: i) why are you using `sudo` if the script is already running as root? ii) does `reboot` work on 14.04? Try it from the command line manually. If not, try `shutdown -r now` or `systemctl reboot` (assuming 14.04 had systemctl, I don't remember). Also, please clarify whether you see the `aserver has stopped...` message in your log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out! The problem was a path issue for reboot. I had to put "sudo /sbin/reboot now" in arewerunning.sh. I had read about the path issues for other commands but didn't put two and two together that reboot was also a command whose path might have been tampered with.